# Why can't I get the Jenkins Powershell plugin to work?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0, jenkins-plugins

Why can't I get the Jenkins "Powershell plugin" to work?

I can run a powershell script on Jenkins using a "Execute windows batch command" build step with the following command:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File script.ps1
```

But I am unable to run a powershell script with the Jenkins "Powershell plugin" using the "Windows Powershell" build step and this command, because of a Windows Execution policy not set error disallowing it to run:

```
script.ps1
```

Does anyone know the proper arg to give the Jenkins "Powershell Plugin" for it to succesfully run a script?  Otherwise, I will just use the batch script work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct thing to do is to set an execution policy on your machine (a one-time action), at which point you won't need to bypass it every time, and the Jenkins plugin should "just work".  Are you unable to?

A reasonable starting setting would be RemoteSigned, which will allow you to execute local scripts fine but would still disallow scripts downloaded from the internet.

From an elevated PowerShell prompt, you would run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

See also: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849812.aspx

UPDATE: excerpt from Help on applying policy and how it's supposed to behave:

> If you set the execution policy for the local computer (the default)
>   or the current user, the change is saved in the registry and remains
>   effective until you change it again.

Of course, if your machine is on a Domain, then Group Policy could revert this.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to stick.  Is it supposed to be global and permanent when you do it?  If so, I never noticed.

Comment: It is permanent, but it looks like from what you found that it has scope specific to your user by default

Comment: Is your Jenkins box on a Domain? It's possible the reason it isn't sticking is that group policy is defining a specific ExecutionPolicy.

Comment: You might be right.  I have 2 domains, and they are on different domains, and they seem to exhibit different behavior.  I'll need to examine more closely.  Thanks for the heads up.  I do believe you are right, and it is normally persistent.

Comment: It should be a very reasonable request to a domain admin to request RemoteSigned ExecutionPolicy for your build machine in Group Policy. Alternatively, you could get clever and try to set the executionPolicy for the "SYSTEM" user's "user" scope somehow...

Comment: I think there is a way to set a folder to allow scripts to run, always. I can't remember whether it's policy, in a config, or a registry entry. Basically, you're saying "allow any script in here to run".  But maybe that was MS Access, lol.

Answer (score 3):

For a reboot-proof solution, put this single line

`powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force`

in a batch file in the All Users *Startup* folder, which on Windows 7 is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

(or you can get there by clicking *Start* -> *All Programs*, right-click *Startup* and click *Open All Users*)

This is how I got Jenkins executing PS scripts on a domain machine subject to Group Policy, without having to involve the sys admin guys ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea but the answer I marked  as accepted is working for me persistently without having to do the startup script.

Answer (score 2):

After experimentation, I realized that since Jenkins is running as a service as the System user, then the powershell scope is different than the scope used by my terminal services login session.

This script works for me and seems to properly set the registry keys so that the setting is persistent across reboots and new logins.

```
# SetExecutionPolicyToRemoteSigned.ps1
# Need to run this after every server reboot.
Write-Output "Setting local Powershell policy to RemoteSigned"
Write-Output ""

Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser Undefined -Force
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope Process Undefined -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope LocalMachine Undefined -Force

Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope Process RemoteSigned -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope LocalMachine RemoteSigned -Force

Write-Output "Finished."

Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
Start-Sleep -s 10
```